# HTML Character Encoding

Tags: html, character-encoding

When outputting HTML content from a database, some encoded characters are being properly interpreted by the browser while others are not.

For example, `%20` properly becomes a space, but `%AE` does not become the registered trademark symbol.

Am I missing some sort of content encoding specifier?

(note: I cannot realistically change the content to, for example, `&reg;` as I do not have control over the input editor's generated markup)

Comment: Well, `%AE` is not a valid HTML escape sequence.  What software is pre-processing the text you emit?  What character set does it use?

Comment: `%20` and `%AE` are URL encodings, not HTML encodings.

Answer (score 2):

`%AE` is not valid for HTML safe ASCII,
You can view the table here: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

It looks like you are dealing with Windows Word encoding (windows-1252?? something like that) it really will NOT convert to html safe, unless you do some sort of translation in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

The byte `AE` is the [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) representation for the registered trademark. If you don't see anything, then apparently the URL decoder is using other charset to URL-decode it. In for example [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout), this byte does not represent any valid character.

To fix this, you need to URL-decode it using ISO-8859-1, or to convert the existing data to be URL-encoded using UTF-8.

That said, you should not confuse [HTML(XML) encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) like `&reg;` with [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) like `%AE`.

Answer (score 2):

The '%20' encoding is URL encoding. It's only useful for URLs, not for displaying HTML.

If you want to display the reg character in an HTML page, you have two options: Either use an HTML entity, or transmit your page as UTF-8.

If you do decide to use the entity code, it's fairly simple to convert them en-masse, since you can use numeric entities; you don't have to use the named entities -- ie use `&#174;` rather than `&#reg;`.

If you need to know entity codes for every character, I find this cheat-sheet very helpful: http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/

Answer (score 0):

What server side language are you using?  Check for a URL Decode function.

Comment: I did need to URL Decode, though I also mistakenly had <meta charset="utf-8"> in the page which was causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php you can use `urldecode()` but you should be careful about `+` characters.